# Angular 9: set default value with async pipe doesn't update form validity

Tags: angular, validation, default-value, async-pipe

I have a `FormGroup`, let's call it `groupForm`, that contains a control which is a group of radio buttons:

```js
this.groupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   radioGroup: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

I have a `BehaviorSubject` in a service, which I'd like to use to set the default value of that group. I'd like to use an `async` pipe to do it. So in my template I do something like this:

```html
<mat-radio-group formControlName='radioGroup' [value]="selection$ | async"> 
... radio buttons here ...
</mat-radio-group>
```

Then, in the same template I am using the validity of the groupForm to enable a button.

The problem is, although in the UI the correct radio button appears selected, the form is still invalid and the button appears disabled. I tried the following workaround in code:

```js
this.selection$ = this.selection$.pipe(
    tap(value => this.groupForm.get('radioGroup').setValue(value);
)
```

and it worked. But I am wondering if I am missing something and I can avoid using this workaround.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems the ControlValueAcessor's onChange is not being called inside the library. Maybe you should create an issue about that in Material's repo, on Github.

Comment: it's not a work arround, it's the way to do it. When you use `[value]` NOT change the value of formControl -only change the "display value" of the input-. futhermore, you should not use [value] in a input that yet has formCntrolName or [formControl] or [(ngModel)]. I want to say that to give value to a FormControl you need use "setValue" or "pathValue" or give the value when you create it

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the expected behavior. This [issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10214) involving `mat-select` reports basically the same problem and it was considered a bug by the Material team.